# HTML Multi Select Submit breaks when values alread added

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I found something strange, I have 2 selects columns. You can select values and push it to the second select using jquery. This works perfectly when I submit and my second select had no values.

First Select field:

```
<select style="width: 100%;" name="extensions" id="extensions" multiple="multiple" size="10" class="" >
<?php
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT name from MyTable");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
           echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>";
        }
?>
</select>
```

The move buttons:

```
<input class="" type="button" id="right" value=">">
<input class="" type="button" id="left" value="<">
```

Second select field:

```
<select style="width: 100%;" name="queuemembers[]" id="queuemembers" multiple="multiple" class="" size="10">
</select>
```

My Jquery Code:

```
$('#left').click(function () {
   $('#queuemembers option:selected').appendTo('#extensions');
});
$('#right').on('click', function () {
   $('#extensions option:selected').appendTo('#queuemembers');
});
```

When I submit the form I can use PHP to get the POST value from my second select.

```
print_r($_POST['queuemembers']);
```

returns

```
Array ( [0] => MyName [1] => SistersName )
```

Perfect I remove all the values I moved to this select.

### ---------------------

This is where it breaks:

First Select field:

```
<select style="width: 100%;" name="extensions" id="extensions" multiple="multiple" size="10" class="" >
<?php
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT name from MyTable");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
           echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>";
        }
?>
</select>
```

The move buttons:

```
<input class="" type="button" id="right" value=">">
<input class="" type="button" id="left" value="<">
```

Second select field:

```
<select style="width: 100%;" name="queuemembers[]" id="queuemembers" multiple="multiple" class="" size="10">
<?php
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT name from MyTable WHERE name = 'MyName'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
           echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>";
        }
?>
</select>
```

I have now added a value to the second select before I submit.

My Jquery Code:

```
$('#left').click(function () {
   $('#queuemembers option:selected').appendTo('#extensions');
});
$('#right').on('click', function () {
   $('#extensions option:selected').appendTo('#queuemembers');
});
```

When I submit the form and use PHP to get the POST value from my second select, it doesn't return the value that was add with the while loop. It will only display the values received from first select column.

```
print_r($_POST['queuemembers']);
```

returns

```
Array ( [0] => SistersName )
```

I suspect it might have to do with the jquery code but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, I was not forcing the option to be selected

Second select field:

```
<select style="width: 100%;" name="queuemembers[]" id="queuemembers" multiple="multiple" class="" size="10">
<?php
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT name from MyTable WHERE name = 'MyName'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo "<option value='$row[0]' selected>$row[0]</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Adding the selected attribute fixed it.

Just have to find a way to let jquery do it, to avoid uses unselecting a value.

Comment: You sould also really stop using `mysql_*` functions. They've been deprecated for over 3 years now and they will no longer work in PHP 7+. Considder using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead in combination with [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: So you need to get all option values from queuemembers with jquery? Is not clear what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I got my jquery on submit to force select the values:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
   $('#queuemembers option').prop('selected', true);
});
```